# Teradata Partitioning Usage in Views

Tags: teradata

I have a table which is partitioned on a date column.
TRANS_DT between '2010-01-0' and '2030-12-31' EACH INTERNAL '1' MONTH.

A view is created on the table where the TRANS_DT is CAST as CAST(CAST(TRANS_DT AS DATE FORMAT 'MMM-YYYY') AS VARCHAR(8)) to denote date like 'MAR-2021'.

When SQL's are running on the VIEW by applying condition as TRANS_DT='MAR-2021', the explain plan states that a full table scan is performed instead of Partition Level Scan.

Comment: So what happens if you query the table directly, using an actual date?

Comment: This does not appear to be a question. Your filter condition is on an expression result and not on the column value directly, so static partition elimination does not happen. If you use a calendar table to map 'MMM-YYYY' text values to actual dates and join to that in a view, you may get dynamic partition elimination.